# How can I tell if a buffer is already visible?

Tags: buffers, window, visibility

I'd like to have the following code in my library:

```
(when (not (buffer-visible-p es-results-buffer))
  (delete-other-windows)
  (view-buffer-other-window es-results-buffer))
```

However, I haven't been able to find a function for `buffer-visible-p`. Is there such a function?

Comment: `results-buffer` or `es-results-buffer`?

Comment: @sds whoops typo, I fixed it, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`get-buffer-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers-and-Windows.html), or you can iterate over the list of all visible windows yourself.